# Java 9 Module / Service System - get an instanced service provider by name, or a new one if none exists?

Tags: java, java-9, java-module, service-provider

I am trying to learn about the Java 9 Services, so this is might not be an ideal scenario but what I am using to try to learn services, specifically...

I am trying to create a service for DatabaseConnection classes. There might be a provider for MySQL, another for SQLServer, etc. An application might need three SQLServer connections, and two MySQL connections. So, for this, the application is able to set a connection name as part of the init method.

So, I am trying to create a method that will live in the Service interface, and accept two arguments, the name of the connection, and the database engine. It should return an already instantiated provider if one exists, or create a new one (assuming a proper provider is defined), but I can't seem to make this happen. It just returns the already instantiated version.

This is the method I have:

```
public static DatabaseConnection getDBCByNameEngine(String name, String dbEngine) throws NoProviderException
{
    ServiceLoader<DatabaseConnection> dbsl = ServiceLoader.load(DatabaseConnection.class);
    // See if the connection with that name exists
    for (Databaseconnection dbco : dbsl) {
        if (dbco.getName().equals(name)) return dbco;
    }
    // Create a new instance
    Optional<DatabaseConnection> dbc = dbcs.stream()
        // This filter is checking an annotation Engine(name="whatever")
        .filter(provider -> engineMatches(provider.type(), engineName);
        .map(ServiceLoader.Provider::get)
        .findFirst();
     if (dbc.isPresent()) {
         dbc.setName(name);
         return dbc;
     }
}
```

I have create a Service, which is an interface called DatabaseConnection:

```
public interface DatabaseConnection
{
    public static getDBCByNameEngine(String name, String dbEngine) throws NoProviderException
    {
        // see above
    }
    void init(connectionName, connectionString, String username, String password);
    String getName();
    // DB stuff
}
```

What happens when I call the method the first time for a SQLServer provider named conn1 is I get a new instance named conn1. The second time I call for a SQLSerer provider named conn2, I get the same instance, renamed conn2.

Comment: How many implementations of `DatabaseConnection` do you have? Where are they located? Does every module which provides an implementation have a `provides` module directive in it's module-info like `provides com.example.DatabaseConnection with com.example.foo.BarDatabaseConnection`? Does the module which contains the interface itself provide an implementation? Does the module which contains the interface itself use the service? Does every implementation have a public no-args constructor or a public static no-args method returning the `DatabaseConnection` interface called `provider`?

Comment: I have two implementations of `DatabaseConnection`. They are in the same module as the interface. Each module has a provides. There is a testing / proof of concept user in the same module. They both have public no-args constructors.